# Every closed set in $\mathbb R^2$ is boundary of some other subset

Tags: general-topology

A problem is bugging me many years after I first met it:

> Prove that any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the boundary of some set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I have toyed with this problem several times over the last 20 years, but I have never managed to either prove it, or conversely prove that the question as posed is in some way wrong.

I can't remember which book I found the question in originally (but I am pretty sure that is exactly the question as it appeared in the book).

Any help, with either the topology or the source would be gratefully received!

Comment: Does "frontier" mean [boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29)?

Comment: Yes, I am sure the book used "frontier" to mean "boundary".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a very elementary way to solve this, that is also much more widely applicable.

> Let $Y$ be a topological space that can be partitioned into dense subsets $D$ and $E$. If $X \subset Y$ is closed, then there is a $V \subset X$ such that $\operatorname{Fr} V = X$.

Take $V = X \setminus (D \cap \operatorname{Int} X)$. Then since $V \subset X$ we have $\operatorname{Cl} V \subset \operatorname{Cl} X$, and $\operatorname{Fr} V \subset X$ and $E \cap \operatorname{Int} X$ dense in $\operatorname{Int} X$, therefore $\operatorname{Cl} V = X$. On the other hand $Y \setminus  X$ is dense in $Y \setminus \operatorname{Int} X$ and $D \cap \operatorname{Int} X$ is dense in $\operatorname{Int} X$, therefore $\operatorname{Int} V = \emptyset$. It follows that $ \operatorname{Fr} V = X$.

---

**Some additional information:**

The question probably came from Willard's *General topology*, problem 3 B.

As Henno Brandsma pointed out in a comment, a space that can be partitioned into
two dense subsets is called *resolvable*. For some examples of irresolvable spaces, see the answer to ["Is a perfect set a boundary?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/540205/3457).

A somewhat stronger result can be found in ["Any two disjoint open sets are the interior and exterior of some set"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752494/any-two-disjoint-open-sets-are-the-interior-and-exterior-of-some-set).

Comment: Another way to phrase your result is that in a topological space $Y$, "every closed set is a boundary" is equivalent to "$Y$ is a boundary".

Comment: @Chris Eagle: That is a very nice way to put it. In fact it can be proved along the same lines that a closed subset of any boundary is also a boundary.

Comment: Such a space $Y$ is called resolvable. Just FYI.

Comment: Dear @NielsJ.Diepeveen I'm reading your proof, could you give some help to understand it? I don't know how to prove that  $\operatorname{Cl} V=X$ and $\operatorname{Int} V=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 19):

Any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is second countable, and hence separable. So if $X$ is your closed subspace, then let $A$ be a countable subset of $X$ that is dense in $X$. Then the closure of $A$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) is $X$, while the interior of $A$ is empty (since any nontrivial open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is uncountable). Thus $X$ is the boundary of $A$.

Comment: That would seem to do it - many thanks. I think I was somewhat blinded by the fact that the problem appeared in one of the first chapters of the book, well before concepts such as second countable had been introduced.

Answer (score 0):

@Math23: I also had problems convincing myself about those facts in the proof. I proceeded as follows:

A) Try to see that we can write $V=\left(\mathrm{Int\,}X\cap E\right)\cup\mathrm{Fr}\,X$. With this, convince yourself that $\mathrm{Cl}\,V\supset X$. Then, it's easy to see that $\mathrm{Cl}\,V\subset X$ (because $V\subset X$) and so $\mathrm{Cl}\,V=X$.

B) Notice that we can also write $V=X\cap\left[E\cup\mathrm{Cl}\left(Y\setminus X\right)\right]$. With this, convince yourself that $\mathrm{Int}\,V\subset \mathrm{Int}\,X\cap E$ and this implies $\mathrm{Int}\,V=\emptyset$. However, I now notice that Niels' argument on this is not that hard to see. What it says is that for every nhood of any point $y\in Y$ (regardless of $y$ being inside or outside $\mathrm{Int}\, X$) we can find points in that nhood that don't belong to $V$.