# Is a perfect set a boundary?

Tags: general-topology

In a topological space, is a perfect set (i.e. closed with no isolated points) always the boundary of some set?

Comment: In a second-countable space, yes, every closed set is a boundary there. In full generality, no idea yet.

Comment: The answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151265/a-niggling-problem-about-frontier-in-topology implies that this is true iff every space without isolated points can be partitioned into two dense subsets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A topological space is *irresolvable* if there is no dense subset whose complement is also dense. If $X$ is irresolvable and dense-in-itself, then $X$ is a perfect subset of $X$ which is not the boundary of any subset of $X$. Irresolvable dense-in-itself spaces have been constructed by Hewitt and others:

1. E. Hewitt, A problem of set-theoretic topology, Duke Math. J. 10 (1943), 309-333.
2. K. Padmavally, An example of a connected irresolvable Hausdorff space, Duke Math. J. 20 (1953), 513-520.
3. Douglas R. Anderson, On connected irresolvable Hausdorff spaces, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 16 (1965), 463-466.
4. [Guram Bezhanishvili, Ray Mines, and Patrick J. Morandi, Scattered, Hausdorff-reducible, and hereditarily irresolvable spaces, Topology and Appl. 132 (2003) 291-306](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/gbezhani/scattered.pdf).

For an easy example of an irresolvable T$_1$-space with no isolated points, take an infinite set $X$ and a nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $X$, and topologize $X$ by making $\mathcal U$ the collection of all nonempty open sets. This is a [*door space*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Door_space); clearly, a nonempty door space is irresolvable.