# $A\subset R^n$ is closed. Proof that there exists $B \subset R^n$ such that $\partial B=A$

Tags: general-topology

Where $\partial B$ is the frontier or boundary of $B$. I tried using some relationships like:

- $\bar{A} = int(A) \sqcup \partial A$
- $\partial{A} = \partial A^C$
- $int(A^C) = \bar{A}^C$

trying to say that $B=A^C$ and maybe reach something but i didn't reach anything. Another way could be using the definition of frontier and closed sets and try to find something but i haven't been succesful.

I would appreciate a hint, solution or guidance on how to proof the title of the question.

Thank you

Comment: Ok rewrite the question in the corpus plz

Comment: Find some interior empty set that verifies $\bar{B} = A$. You can use that $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is dense

Comment: $B=A$, they are same points.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151265/every-closed-set-in-mathbb-r2-is-boundary-of-some-other-subset

Comment: Elements of $\mathbb R^n$ are not the same as subspaces.

Comment: @BobDobbs that only works when $A$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: You certainly mean $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ and  $B \subset \mathbb R^n$.